# InvocationTargetException в конструкторе класса

Tags: android, java

У меня сложная структура для отображения на экране. Я ее строю с помощью XML лейаутов. Для вертикальной ориентации и портретной лейауты разные.

При перевороте экрана лейауты перерисовываются и инициализируются элементы GUI.
На горизонтальном лейауте я использую кастомный **RelativeLayout**, в котором переопределяю метод **onMeasure()**.

При нескольких быстрых переворотах экрана возникает ошибка

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: 
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #146: Error inflating class <unknown>`

ссылка идет на элемент моего **CustomRelativeLayout** и ниже в стектрейсе **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException** с ссылкой на конструктор моего кастомного класса.

Подозреваю, что активити просто не успевает уничтожится и стартовать снова но как это исправить не имею ни малейшего понятия. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Исключение `InvocationTargetException` возникает, если метод, вызванный через reflection, выкинул исключение сам. В данном случае получается, что ваш кастомный класс в конструкторе выкинул исключение. Соответственно надо искать ошибку в конструкторе вашего класса (или в методах, которые он вызывает). Само исходное исключение должно быть указано в причине `InvocationTargetException` (в стектрейсе должно быть ещё ниже строчки **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, ошибка в парсинге XML-я с разметкой. Нужно бы посмотреть на разметку...а так...гадание.
Другая мысль: если нет разметки, а есть код вьюхи(как я понимаю у вас кастомная вьюха), то нужно взглянуть на ее код. Возможно не хватает конструктора с нужными параметрами.